# Android toolbar not hiding entirely (> Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-toolbar

In my app I use `AppBarLayout` with `Toolbar` inside it as my support action bar. I want it to hide/show when user is scrolling content. On KitKat everything works fine, but on Lollipop and Marshmallow Toolbar isn't scrolling its full height. [Screen with toolbar fully scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huofq.png)

My layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="(...)">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app__content"
        layout="@layout/app_bar__main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:name="(...)"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment__navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`app_bar__main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="(...)">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app__appbarlayout__action_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app__toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar__height"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar__background"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/app_content__main" />

    <include android:id="@+id/app__layout__bottom_bar"
        layout="@layout/layout__bottom_bar" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`app_content__main.xml` is just FrameLayout into which I am adding fragments. I use `support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0` and `support:design:23.2.0` (cannot use 23.3.0 because of another bug with toolbar). It was working with 23.0.0, but is there any way I can do it work without moving to this previous version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from the CoordinatorLayout.